# Copying files from source folder to target folder

Tags: vbscript, file-copying

Hi I'm trying to copy a file from source to target folder. But I'm getting an error "Bad File name or number" when im running it.

Here is my code:

```
Option Explicit
Dim srcFolder, trgFolder

srcFolder = "\\sunpowercorp.com\spap\SPMM-QA\Public-Read_Write\SPMM QA Documents\Dominic Yumul\Toshiba Monthly Quality Report"
trgFolder = "http:\\dms\departments\QUALITY\Quality Ops in the Box\Quality Ops in the Box library\025 SPMM QA Staff Documents\Toshiba Monthly Quality Report"

CopyFilesAndFolders srcFolder, trgFolder
WScript.Quit

Sub CopyFilesAndFolders(ByVal strSource, ByVal strDestination)
    Dim ObjFSO, ObjFolder, ObjSubFolder, ObjFile, files
    Dim TargetPath
    Set ObjFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    'connecting to the folder where is going to be searched
    Set ObjFolder = ObjFSO.GetFolder(strSource)
    TargetPath = Replace (objFolder.path & "\", strSource, strDestination,1,-1,vbTextCompare)
    If Not ObjFSO.FolderExists (TargetPath) Then ObjFSO.CreateFolder (TargetPath)
    Err.clear
    On Error Resume Next
    'Check all files in a folder
    For Each objFile In ObjFolder.files
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no files in folder
        On Error goto 0
        If CheckToCopyFile (objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name) Then 
            objFSO.copyfile objFile.path, TargetPath & "\" & objFile.name, True
        End If
    Next
    'Recurse through all of the subfolders
    On Error Resume Next
    Err.clear
    For Each objSubFolder In ObjFolder.subFolders
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then Exit For 'If no permission or no subfolder in folder
        On Error goto 0
        'For each found subfolder there will be searched for files
        CopyFilesAndFolders ObjSubFolder.Path & "\", TargetPath & ObjSubFolder.name & "\"
    Next
    Set ObjFile = Nothing
    Set ObjSubFolder = Nothing
    Set ObjFolder = Nothing
    Set ObjFSO = Nothing
End Sub

Function CheckToCopyFile(ByVal strSourceFilePath, ByVal strDestFilePath)
    Dim oFSO, oFile, SourceFileModTime, DestFileModTime
    CheckToCopyFile = True
    Set oFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    If Not oFSO.FileExists (strDestFilePath) Then Exit Function
    Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile (strSourceFilePath)
    SourceFileModTime = oFile.DateLastModified
    Set oFile = Nothing
    Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile (strDestFilePath)
    DestFileModTime = oFile.DateLastModified
    Set oFile = Nothing
    If SourceFileModTime =< DestFileModTime Then CheckToCopyFile = False
    Set oFSO = Nothing
End Function
```

I do not know what line I am getting the error.

Comment: You can't copy files to a web server using FSO.

Comment: then how can i do that?

Comment: This shows you how to interact with web servers at it's most basic. You need to know what to send the server. It's usually a post command.  You can get Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/ which allows you to see what is being sent. You can use vbscript here to do what the browser is doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480969/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-website-using-batch-script

Comment: Is the destination a SharePoint or a regular webserver?

Comment: Yes the destination is Sharepoint

Answer (score 0):

On Windows Vista and newer you should be able to [map](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kst88h6.aspx) SharePoint libraries to drive letters using WebDAV as described in [this blog post](https://sysengineers.wordpress.com/2012/07/04/networkmapping-to-sharepoint-using-vbs/):

```
Set net = CreateObject("WScript.Network")
net.MapNetworkDrive "X:", "\\sp.example.org@SSL\site\Shared Documents\"
```

Then copy your files to the mapped drive using `FileSystemObject` methods.