# Scheduled export of Google Sheet to xlsx using bat-file

Tags: excel, batch-file, google-sheets, export, export-to-excel

I have found an easy way to download a Google Sheet as xlsx. Just navigate to:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET-ID/export?exportFormat=xlsx

I can schedule to download this xlsx with a batch-file:

```
start "" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SHEET-ID/export?exportFormat=xlsx
```

The problem is that my browser sets the download path, and creates duplicates, e.g. download.xlsx, download(1).xlsx, download(2).xlsx etc.

I found another solution using bitsadmin, but have some problems with it.

```
bitsadmin.exe /transfer "MyExport" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET-ID/export?exportFormat=xlsx C:\MyDir\GoogleSheet.xlsx
```

This allows me to choose download dir and filename, which overwrites each time I run it. However, the examples I saw using bitsadmin is linking directly to a file, e.g. url.com/download.zip. My link is not directly to a file, and hence my downloaded .xlsx is empty.

Can I solve this? I would prefer not using 3rd party applications.

Thank you.

Comment: Does Excel's web query work, maybe on the file direct in the browser rather than downloading. Choose a sheet that is a query sheet. Alt D, D, W. Then link the data you want from the page to a new sheet. Failing that you can get Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/

Comment: Does Excel's web query work, maybe on the file direct in the browser rather than downloading. Choose a sheet that is a query sheet. Alt D, D, W. Then link the data you want from the page to a new sheet. Failing that you can get Fiddler https://www.telerik.com/ which allows you to see what is being sent. You can use vbscript here to do what the browser is doing. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480969/how-to-read-the-content-of-a-website-using-batch-script

Comment: Hello Noodles!

Do you mean fetch external data from the web? I have tried that, it doesn't work :( I have Excel 2010.

Comment: Have to learn VBScript and HTTP protocol.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it like this:

```
::open browser and download    
start "" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET-ID/export?exportFormat=xlsx
::create timeout to give time to download
timeout /t 10
::move download to overwrite old version
move /Y "C:\Users\Bob\Downloads\Name of Spreadsheet (1).xlsx" "C:\Dir\Name of Spreadsheet.xlsx"
::optional, close browser
taskkill /F /IM chrome.exe /T
```

Comment: Was thinking this was the way i would suggest doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Found this rather old post but answer it anyways :)

Easiest way to make it save and any given location directly is by adding the desired path.

Example:
start "" https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/SPREADSHEET-ID/export?exportFormat=xlsx C:\Users\Username\Desktop

Comment: The link doesn't work or doesn't have public access